# If Else in Gawk

Tags: awk

I have an example:

```
echo $(seq 9) | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i!=5&&i!=6) {printf "%s ",i}else{printf "%s ",""} print ""}'
1 2 3 4   7 8 9
```

Is it possible to use the shorthand of this command?

```
echo $(seq 9)| awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) (i!=5&&i!=6) ? {printf "%s ",i} : {printf "%s ",""} print ""}'
```

Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible, but not that way. You have to supply expressions to the ternary operator. In AWK `printf` is a statement, so you can not use it there, like you can neither have `{}` either.

As you not need two `printf` statements anyway, better write it like this:

```
seq -s ' ' 9 | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s ", i!=5&&i!=6 ? i : ""; print ""}'
```